# Why is this require statement not working?

Tags: actions, oop

I am faced with this strange issue when the script loads it gives me an error:

> [04-Oct-2015 18:36:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(../main/otherfile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\main\main-file.php on line 30

why is the otherfile.php not loading correctly ? 
Here are the contents of the files:

Content of **main-file.php**

```
require '../inc/otherfile.php';
```

Content of **myplugin.php**

```
class Myplugin{
    function __construct(){
        add_action( 'init', array('this',init) );
    }

    function init(){
        require 'main/main-file.php';
    }

}
new Myplugin;
```

**file structure**

```
myplugin
    myplugin-class.php
    main
        main-file.php
    inc
        otherfile.php
        otherfile3.php
```

Comment: Looking at your file structure, there is no `otherfile.php`.  Assuming this is just a typo, look at the relative path in the PHP warning.  It's off one level.

Comment: i have updated the question. thanks for pointing out that that was off one level.

Comment: By 'off one level' I mean that the warning is showing you where it is trying to find your include.  Adjust your statement accordingly.  Hope that helps.